# Changing app id configured in XCode 4

Tags: xcode4

Where do I change the originally configured app id in XCode 4?

I have one name in the Provisioning Portal and another in XCode and I would like to change XCode so they're one and the same.

Comment: did you manage to get this working? In my Boundle identifier I find the following: **com.yourcompany.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}** Does this sound correct to you? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You will have to edit the file [project-name]-Info.plist to change the prefix of the Bundle identifier to match the provisioning profile.

Dave

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on this?

Comment: if you using xcode4.3.3,  [project-name]-Info.plist  should be in "Supporting Files" folder of your xcode project

Comment: So the bundle identifier is the app id?